Sveltekit, Pocketbase SDK, request made as Guest, not with AuthRecord
Im quite new to Typescript, Sveltekit and Pocketbase. But have some general beginners experience. It's my hobby to learn it now.
I couldn't find an answer elsewhere.
If i make a pocketbase api request with the SDK within my +layout.server.ts, the request is as guest. But if i do it from within a +page.server.ts, say within the profile route, it does work and is authenticated.
Im learning my way through sveltekit and typescript with a small project to create an App for my soccer team, so parents can see which Kids they have, and in which team their kid is and/or which matches or trainings they have in the future.
If a user (parent) is authenticated, I'd like to have the player's data available in multiple routes. That's why i did it in +layout.server.ts, and not in a specific route.
What am I missing?
This is my layout file:
// +layout.server.ts

import { pocketbase } from '$lib/db/client'; // Adjust the import path as needed
import type { LayoutServerLoad } from './$types';
import type { User, Player } from '$lib/types'; // Adjust the import path as needed

export const load: LayoutServerLoad = async ({ locals }) => {
    if (locals.user) {
        try {
            console.log('Authenticated user:', locals.user.name); 
            const user: User = {
                _id: locals.user.id,
                name: locals.user.name,
                avatar: locals.user.avatar ? locals.user.avatar : undefined,
                avatarUrl: locals.user.avatarUrl ? locals.user.avatarUrl : undefined,
                email: locals.user.email,
                username: locals.user.username
            };

            let players: any[] = []; 
            if (locals.user.id) {
                console.log('Fetching players for user ID:', locals.user.id);
                const playerQuery = await pocketbase.collection('players').getList(1, 50, {
                    owned: locals.user.id
                });

                players = playerQuery.items;
                console.log('Players fetched:', players); 
            }

            return {
                user,
                players
            };
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching user or players:', error);
            return { user: {} as User, players: [] }; 
        }
    }
    return {}; 
};



I was expecting the request for players, owned by locals.user.id, to be authenticated with the local user. So that the API rules can only accept request from users who own specific players, and can only show those players.
